# Select common columns between the select company ID's from table based on NULL fields?

Tags: mysql

I have an structure for the table as below

```
calling_numb |called_num|cell_id|calling_loc|called_loc|company|cell_type|called_reg|c_site
+937779832423|+93799234323|C8435|   NULL    | NULL     | 77    | Nokia   | 44       |443543
+937883432424|+93700335234|S6700| 4     | 9        | 788   | 435341  | NULL     | NULL
+937999343324|+93788324234|W580 | Ghazni    |   Herat  | 799   | Kabul   | NULL     | NULL
+937003556322|+93788342343|K860 | 01        |   NULL   | 700   | NULL    | NULL     | 6823
+937778342453|+93700453423|L900 | 05        | 12       | 77    | Samsung | NULL     | NULL
+937994354356|+93789345435|K334 | Ghazni    | Herat    | 799   | Nokia   | NULL     | 3345
+937004353455|+93799033453|S6790| NULL      | NULL     | 700   | NULL    | xYZ      |34543
```

Brief structure of table in real table it has allot of fields,Now what i want to get is the column name of those fields that are common for all of companies by checking the value of company for example:

```
select column_name from table where company = 77 
intersect 
select column_name from table where company = 799 
intersect 
select column_name from table where company = 700 
intersect 
select column_name from table where company = 788
```

The output i want to have is the `calling_number`, `called_number`, `cell_id` which are common for four company

> i receive all information of a SIM from telecom companies for example i save information from company A and for other SIM from company B and the same for C , and D these company has some same field for data they store that i save those fields in the same column for all company but also each company has seprate field that is not the same for other company now what i want to get is the column name from table that is same for all company and their value is not null for all company

Comment: please provide the structure of your table and format your code so it becomes readable

Comment: it sounds like you want to be using JOINs but it would help if you tried to write some code first, and came back and posted what you tried.

Comment: @user2357059 I have update that comment to your question so others can read it, as it is what you want to accomplish here and what describe the best your issue. Unhappily I don't see any easy way to achieve what you want without using trigger or pre processing the data at the code side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below code will work for you sure.**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns where table_name='your_table_name'");
$columns = mysqli_fetch_array($result);/*This will retreive all columns from the specified tablename*/
$outcols=array();
$count=count($columns);
$i=0;
$inc=0;
while($i<$count)
{
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ".$columns[$i]." FROM your_table_name WHERE ".$columns[$i]." IS NULL");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(count($row)<=0)
{
$outcols[$inc]=$columns[$i];
$inc++;
}
$i++;
}
print_r($result);
```

> The above code is coded by my own.Check it out.Iam sure it will help
>   you.If you are using PHP to access MySQL Database.
>   The above code will print all column names whose data are not null in the specified table.

Comment: it is almost true but in first query statement i need to check also for = 0 condition i used that but bring false because it assume all fields null + 0 it means no any fields is out of these two condition

Comment: I have use count($row)<=0 means.After the above query executes.MySQL fills the $row array with data,when the column is NULL.If any field in the row is equal to NULL value.Then the data will be added to the $row array.That if count($row) less than or equals zero means there is no null value in the column specified."<=0" condition is used for checking if the array is empty or underflowed.If it is empty it will be declared that there is no NULL values in the column.Detailed description is given.**VOTE UP**

Comment: Thanks allot for helping finally this was the solution i wanted just i changed some simple portion of that thanks again from you!

Comment: Yes welcome.Please **UPVOTE** for me and mark as answer.It will great for my efforts.This is the only thing you can do for me,If you are wishing to do anything for me.

Comment: but i can't vote up when i do that it says i should have 15 reputation but i have 5 reputation

Comment: I can increase for you something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using mysql.you can get the coloumn name like this.

> You can get the results that calling_number,called_number and cell_id are duplicates or common for the specified company such as company 77.

```
SELECT calling_number,called_number,cell_id 
from table_name 
where company IN (77,799,700,788) 
GROUP BY calling_number,called_number,cell_id 
HAVING count(*)>1
```

I think this will surely help you as you needed.
LIKE

> The output i want to have is the calling_number, called_number,
>   cell_id which are common for four company

Comment: The main problem for me is this that the common Not Null fields for all company is not cleared for me may be in future some other fields also can be same

Comment: As your EDIT specifies.You need all fields which are common for all company and whose values are not null for all company.Is it?

Comment: Yeah finally this was the main thing i want to take

Comment: You mean any one field has a null value that want to be omitted.

Comment: Yeah but just i should take the column name not their value in result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
from table_name 
where data is not null
```

***repeat `<column>` IS NOT NULL for each column you need***

Comment: i don't know all the columns name that are common because the common fields for company may be the other fields of table in future or may be i store data of some other companies also in future

Comment: You mean.If any field found to be NULL.Then the row is omitted.

Comment: no i don't want to take the row to be care of that just i want the name of those columns that their values are not not null when company is IN(77,788,799,700) means those columns should not be null for these companies

Comment: For are you have privilege or can execute dynamic sql code.It will simplifies the matter.But its not possible to acheive this in Standard query.It is possible by specifiying each and every column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
from table_name 
where calling_numb is not null and called_num is not null and cell_id is not null and calling_loc is not null and called_loc is not null and company is not null and cell_type is not null and called_reg is not null and c_site is not null
```

> This will retreives all datas which is not null.

Comment: I has more than 200 fields in table how should i check all of them for not null? and also i don't want to take the data just want to take the column name

Answer (score 0):

For getting the column name we want to seek for the database information_schema.In which MySQL stores all datas like table name,column name,etc.As per your need.It goes like this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) nonnull_columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
AND is_nullable = 'NO'
```

> This will definitely help you.

Comment: if some common field is not null but can accept null as value so it will work? does is_nullable refer to the table schema definition of fields that can accept null or no or to the current state of fields?

Comment: is_nullable refers to the column can accept a null value or not

Comment: I checked your query but this returned only those fields that i defined them as not null fields during table creation schema here just i have one field that can't accept null which is the key of table so how can i get all columns that has value for all company not to check if the column accept null or no?

Comment: I have already told you that.This will make some complications when using standard query.So are you ready with Dynamic MySQL.We can just create a For loop and do it.It is easy as an apple pie.

Comment: Which lanuage you are using the Database with.